# how to import excel to datagrid, then filter by db values

Tags: excel, vb.net, import, datagrid, filtering

my question about import excel to datagridview but there is an extra case.

I have also a oledb database with store code and store names.

I want it to show only store codes from db that are in the database after imported.

my codes here;

```
 Dim conn As OleDbConnection
        Dim dtr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim dts As DataSet
        Dim excel As String
        Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog


        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

        If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

            excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn)



            dts = New DataSet
            dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
            DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Sheet1$]"
            conn.Close()
        End If
```

firstly sorry for my terrible english :)

images as follows;

[Main Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd2NV.jpg)

[Store List Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttIeV.jpg)

I want only the ones in the store list to be displayed in datagrid.. :\

Comment: use data view as data source, not data table
https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-use-dataview-rowfilter-property.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is already answered before and besides I provided a link with example. There are many such examples available. Bottom line, OP did not do enough research before asking

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what your current presentation/display looks like, what the problem is, and what your desired presentation/display should look like.  But you have asked about selecting only one part of the data you are importing, which is presumably found in only one column of the imported Excel data.

When the `datatable` is created, it has the columns and rows from the Excel worksheet.  The columns will be data from the first row, and the rows will be the records from the succeeding rows in the worksheet.  You can access both the header data and the row data easily.  The code below is VERY rough but for you to see how to gain access to the data in the `datatable` which you have already very successfully imported in the limited code shown above.

```
Dim columns = datatable.Columns
Dim rows = datatable.Rows
Dim columns1 = columns(0)
Dim rows1 = rows(0)
Dim element1 = rows1(0)
```

Columns will have all the headers, so you can locate the column with the store codes or store names.  Then the rows will have the data for each store.  So above, rows1 is the first row of data and element1 is the data in that row from columns1, and so on.  The `(0)` is the index into the respective collections.

You will, of course, have to write code to extract the data you want and if necessary eliminate duplicates, but the data is all there already.

Hopefully getting the data into a list and then sorting, filtering and selecting the data should be relatively straightforward, but if not, add a comment.  That's kind of a different problem.  You asked about getting only the store codes.

**Added:** Based on your additional images and explanation, you are looking to perform an SQL INNER JOIN operation.  From the w3schools.com page on SQL INNER JOIN, "The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns." This is something you will have to study and learn, but it should provide what you need in this case.  You will need to define and construct both tables and then perform the JOIN.

And, by the way, you could also follow the link provided in the first comment by T.S., and if that solves your problem, it's a far simpler solution.